# Deleting StatusPanel[Jpanel] or MenuBar at Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jpanel, menubar

It is really simple question. How can i delete  StatusPanel[Jpanel] or MenuBar on Netbeans?

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: Does popup menu's Delete item disabled when you right-click on MenuBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete any element of your GUI (created in the NetBeans [Swing GUI Builder](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)) do the following:

1. Select the element you want to delete in the Design view of the Swing GUI Builder;
2. press Delete button on your keyboard.

P.S. Checked in NetBeans 6.8.